# By enabling $http cache, what response time should be expected after initial requests?

Tags: angularjs, caching

I've got {cache:true{ for my $Http GET Requests. I know that even if this is enabled, data is returned asynchronously, but even though, I find he response times surprisingly long.

I'd like to know if this is normal, or to be more clear, shouldn't be expected that the initial request response time is higher to the same (but next) request response time ?

For example,

Cache is enabled for both $http GET requests:

```
/foo/api/yellow
```

This returns some data, after the promise is resolved, taking 3 seconds. I expect this to be cached by Angularjs, since I've enabled cache.

After a few moments, a new request is made:

```
/foo/api/yellow
```

This returns some data, but even though this was supposedly cached in the first request, the response time is the same or higher then 3 seconds. Like I said, I know that even though cache is true, data is returned asynchronously but is the response times normal, or is there something wrong ?

If this is normal, I guess the best thing to do, is create a new service, to save all cached data and then just check if the data is there and get it synchronously maybe ?

My current code looks like this, for the first request:

```
$http.get(MySettings.apiUrl + '/foo/api/yellow', { cache: true });
```

The second request is the same!

I've decided to attach the console log:

```
GET http://foo/api/get_tag_index/

200 OK
        419ms   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_category_posts/?slug=issues-covers

200 OK
        915ms   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_category_posts/?slug=issues-covers

200 OK
        1s  
angula....min.js (line 106)

200 OK
        4.43s   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_category_posts/?slug=cards

200 OK
        8.93s   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_tag_posts/?slug=issue-01

200 OK
        4.51s   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_category_posts/?slug=news

200 OK
        4.51s   
angula....min.js (line 106)
GET http://foo/api/get_category_posts/?slug=cards

200 OK
        3.86s   
angula....min.js (line 106)
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Have you checked that the backend does NOT receive the second GET request. My guess is that it receives it, and angular doesn't actually cache. What's your code? What happens when you debug through angularJS's http sendReq function?

Comment: @JBNizet I thought by enabling Cache, AngularJS wouldn't send the second GET request for me. I didn't really checked that, because I can see from the console that, it's actually sending the GET request (you can see in the log). Should I still debug using http sendReq - I will anyway, hope to update with more info soon. But it-s strange...

Comment: I don't have any idea where the above logs come from, because you didn't tell. Why don't you check if the SERVER receives those requests?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm checking everything at the moment, hope to update with more info. By the way the logs are coming from my firebug console.log()

Comment: What I meant is that I don't know where you add those logging statements in the code. If you just log that your call $http.get(), then obviously they will be logged, even if the cache is enabled. We also don't know how the time logged is measured, because you didn't provide the code.

Comment: I've changed $cacheFactory for "Angular-cache" available at http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/ and it's now working perfectly! Really nice project!